# How Do You Return a Carriage For HTML in SQL

Tags: sql, carriage-return

I am looking to enter a carriage return in a stuff function. Char(13) and Char(10) are not working because after I use the "Stuff Function", it reverts the code into XML. I have tried replacing &#13, &#10, and 
 for the Char(13), but nothing seems to work.

The following code will run but it will return a space when I need it to return carriage:

```
Select Distinct ID, STUFF((Select ' ' + Char(13) + Address) 
                            from dbo.Address ad
                            where ad.id=a.id FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1, '' + char(13)) AS Address
        from dbo.Address a
        group by ID
```

Comment: you will likely need to add an escape sequence to let this pass as CRLF to the HTML (for example add a '\' or &amp; etc)

Comment: Your query works for me.  If you're looking in SSMS grid view that could be the problem.  Grid view does not show carriage returns in column values.  Copy the results and paste them into a text editor and you should see that the carriage return(s) are there.  If you want HTML for rendering you might want to replace the carriage returns with `<br />` or something.